# Code view not working in summernote

Tags: summernote

I am trying to apply summernote, but here code view is not working, I have tried bellow code

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
         codemirror: {
            theme: 'monokai',
            htmlMode:true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'text/html'
        }
        height: 200
});
```

Here html mode is on, but if I write html after select code style it's showing output plane text.For example if I white

```
<html></html>
```

It's showing me nothing in output.How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your JS. Use chrome or Firefox and open the analyser and look if there are some errors that stops executing your javascript.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Under the `console` tab you should get some informations. But normally if you have a correct structure and a div which has the class **summernote**:

```
<div class="summernote">summernote 1</div>
```

Then the div should be replaced by your editor before set out that nothing is missing and working. But i think you miss something or you have loaded something in wrong order and you get an error and you script stops running.